# Listener function for gwt widgets

Tags: gwt

For my project when a button is clicked, the click event should then wait and listen to the next two clicks on different widgets and then connect them so as to form relationship between them.

Right now i an trying to use FocusListener without success. Any suggestion will be of great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would think you'd just want an ClickListener for each object. Handle "enabling" the other two objects in the first object's click event, then when those two objects are clicked on, invoke the method to form the relationship. You don't want to wait in the first object's event handler.